# Store values from exisiting matrix into new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix containing 8 cols and 80k rows. (From an excel file)

Each row has an ID.

I want to store all data with ID no. 1 in a new matrix. And all data with ID no. 2 in a second matrix etc. So each time an ID changes I want to save all the data of a new ID in a new matrix.

There are above 800 ID's.

Ive tried several things w/o luck. Among others:

```
    k = zeros(117,8)
for i =1:80000
    k(i) = i + Dataset(1:i,:)
end
```

The above was only to see if I actually could get the first 117 rows saved in another matrix which didnt succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of the 8 columns contains the ID then you can use logical indexing. For example if column `1` contains the ID, we can first find a list of all different ID values:

```
uniqueIDs = unique(Dataset(:, 1));
```

Then we can create cell array, with the lists of items of a given ID:

```
listsByID = cell(length(uniqueIDs), 1);
for idx = 1:length(uniqueIDs)
    listsByID{idx} = Dataset(Dataset(:, 1) == uniqueIDs(idx), :);
end
```

Running the above on an example dataset:

```
Dataset = [1 0.1 10
           1 0.2 20
           2 0.3 30
           3 0.4 40
           2 0.5 50
           2 0.6 60];
```

Results in:

```
1.0000 0.1000 10.0000
1.0000 0.2000 20.0000

2.0000 0.3000 30.0000
2.0000 0.5000 50.0000
2.0000 0.6000 60.0000

3.0000 0.4000 40.0000
```

Comment: And generally, it is much (much) better to make one cell array, as suggested here, than more over 800 different variables.